# updating linux. Acer chromebook spin 13

Tags: linux, updates, chromebook

Hi all wonder if you can help.

im trying to update my linux in my chromebook terminal with this command

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I get this error . Any help much appreciated !

````
Hit:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release                         
Get:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]                   
Ign:4 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/94 buster InRelease          
Get:5 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Hit:6 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/94 buster Release
Err:7 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
N: Repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '10.9' to '10.11'
E: Repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
E: Repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.```
````

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Hit:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release
```

You've got a typo on this source line.  Edit /etc/apt/sources.list to fix it.

Also, Debian Jessie is ancient.  Your sources should reference buster or bullseye if you've upgraded to it.